# Facebook Actionscript Graph API - Login fails (Adobe Air on IOS)

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, facebook-graph-api, air

I keep getting login failed when i sign into Facebook, below is the code.
The onLogin callback gets called but keeps hitting trace login failed.

I have installed the latest api, and I'm testing this on the MAC using Flash CC.

How would i fix this?

```
package  {


import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.media.*;
import flash.media.Camera;
import flash.media.CameraUI;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.*;  
import flash.ui.Multitouch;
import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import com.facebook.graph.FacebookMobile;

public class test extends MovieClip {

    var webView:StageWebView;
    var vidCon:Video = new Video();
    const APP_ID:String = "299210093578823";
    var extendedPermissions:Array = ["publish_stream","user_about_me"];



    public function test() {
        trace("djdjhdjhdfh");
        Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
        FacebookMobile.init(APP_ID, onInit);                           
        btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onFBLoginClick);
    }

    private function onInit(success:Object, fail:Object):void
    {
        if (success)
        { 
            trace("Already logged in");
        }
        else
        {  
            //btn.enabled = true;
            trace("Not logged in-");
        }
    }

    private function onFBLoginClick(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        trace("ddddd");     
        FacebookMobile.login(onLogin,this.stage, extendedPermissions,getWebView());
    }

    private function getWebView():StageWebView 
    { 
        if(webView) webView.dispose();

        webView = new StageWebView();
        webView.stage=this.stage;
        webView.assignFocus();

        webView.viewPort = new Rectangle(8, 8, stage.stageWidth -16, stage.stageHeight -16 );
        return webView;
    }

    private function onLogin(success:Object, fail:Object):void
    {
        trace("fhfhfhfhf");
        if (success)
        {
            trace("Logged In\n");
        }
        else
        {        
            trace("Login Failed\n");
        }
    }

}

}
```

Comment: what's contained in the two objects? do something like `trace( JSON.stringify( fail ) )` to get the facebook return error

Comment: @divillysausages, hi thankyou. Im trying to print the error but in this version of JSON the methods available are public static function decode( s:String, strict:Boolean = true ):*
  {
   return new JSONDecoder( s, strict ).getValue();
  }

Comment: and public static function encode( o:Object ):String
  {
   return new JSONEncoder( o ).getString();
  }

Comment: JSON is native in AS3 from flash player 11, so if you're above that, you should be able to access `stringify()`. If not, then `encode` should do the same thing. All it's doing it converting an `Object` to a `String` - you could do a `for..in` either

Comment: @divillysausages, could you take a look at  this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24609964/json-fails-when-using-facebook-graph-api

Comment: it's pretty much the same question. For the native JSON part, if you're *targeting* flash player 11 or over, it's a native class (like `XML` and `String`, so you don't need to import the adobe `JSON` class (in fact, get rid of it, as it'll confuse the compiler)

Comment: In any case, to simplify matters, just do this: `for( var key:* in fail ) { trace( "Key '" + key + "' = " + fail[key] ); }` and tell me the result

Comment: the problem is that the Facebook graph api uses this library and thats why I'm getting the error in one of the Facebook graph api objects

Comment: i have removed all the references

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56908/discussion-between-divillysausages-and-redoc01).