# JSON fails when using Facebook Graph API

Tags: ios, json, facebook, flash, facebook-graph-api

I have a code that connects to Facebook, but after Facebook.Login I get log-in failure and I am trying to output the error using `JSON.parse` which doesn't work and I'm trying to use `JSON.decode` which does not work either. I have included the JSON libraries which is `import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON` which I downloaded the latest version from GitHub.

Here is my code below, but it fails when I'm trying to decode the JSON in the `onLogin` Callback.

I also get an error when I compile and run in `FQLMultiQuery` as the library in this class is imported.

```
public function toString():String {
    return JSON.encode(queries);  ----- where it errors 
}
```

-

```
FQLMultiQuery.as, Line 80, Column 16    1061: Call to a possibly undefined method encode through a reference with static type Class.
```

Also when I trace (fail) I do get some text back about my user profile, gives me information about all my user info in JSON format but does not specify any errors in the JSON at all.

This is the class where I make the login to Facebook:

```
package  {  

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.media.*;
    import flash.media.Camera;
    import flash.media.CameraUI;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.*;  
    import flash.ui.Multitouch;
    import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;
    import com.facebook.graph.FacebookMobile;

    import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;

    public class test extends MovieClip {

        var webView:StageWebView;
        var vidCon:Video = new Video();
        const APP_ID:String = "299210093578823";
        var extendedPermissions:Array = ["publish_stream","user_about_me"];


        public function test() {
            trace("djdjhdjhdfh");
            Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
            FacebookMobile.init(APP_ID, onInit);                           
            btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onFBLoginClick);
        }

        private function onInit(success:Object, fail:Object):void
        {
            if (success)
            { 
                trace("Already logged in");
            }
            else
            {  
                //btn.enabled = true;
                trace("Not logged in-");
            }
        }

        private function onFBLoginClick(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            trace("ddddd");     
            FacebookMobile.login(onLogin,this.stage, extendedPermissions,getWebView());
        }

        private function getWebView():StageWebView 
        { 
            if(webView) webView.dispose();

            webView = new StageWebView();
            webView.stage=this.stage;
            webView.assignFocus();

            webView.viewPort = new Rectangle(8, 8, stage.stageWidth -16, stage.stageHeight -16 );
            return webView;
        }

        private function onLogin(success:Object, fail:Object):void
        {
            trace("fjfjfj");
            var obj:String = JSON.decode(fail.toString());
            trace(obj);
            if (success)
            {
                txt.text = "Logged In";
                trace("Logged In\n");
            }
            else
            {        
                txt.text = "Logged Failed";
                trace("Login Failed\n");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: For which version are you compiling SWF? If it's >=11 the you don't need to use as3corelib JSON parser, hence you can remove "import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON", cause JSON now is top level for Actionscript, you might overriding these two JSON modules an that gives problem.

Comment: hi, i excluded the library and still get that error?

Comment: I'm using Air for IOS on Flash CC using action script 3

Comment: Use JSON.parse and also make sure that Json data is correct. Reader here about native Json
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html